# Django: issue with loading static in deployment

Tags: python, django

I know this question has similar ones but nothing has been able make it for me. My static files are not loading although I feel like have followed the procedure well.

I am hoping that a pair a fresh eye could spot the detail that I am missing

```
urls.py

....
if settings.DEBUG:
    setting.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

```
public_urls.py

....
if settings.DEBUG:
    setting.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/staticfiles/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'collected_static')

MEDIA_URL = '/mediafiles/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mediafiles')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles"),
                    ]
```

and then what is in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/django.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 35.180.131.203;

        location / {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/exostocksaas/app.sock;

}
        location /staticfiles/ {
           autoindex on;
           root /home/ubuntu/exostocksaas/inventory4/staticfiles/;
}

}
```

and my errors are that the static files are not loading:

```
GET http://35.180.131.203/css/sb-admin-2.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

and the same for all the statics

Am I missing something obvious here, I am out of things to try and any help would be welcome

Comment: Do you have debug set to true or false?  If False, you have to run `python manage.py collectstatic` that will pull all of your static files into the /staticfiles/ directory

Comment: I have done that, should I put STATIC_ROOT to be to 'staticfiles' rather than 'collected_static'?

Comment: Yes.  Whatever is defined as your STATIC_ROOT is where your static files will go when you run the mentioned command.